# Multiple laptops with same github account and SSH key

Tags: python, git, github

How would I go about setting up one github user and ssh key and then replicating that to several other laptops so they can all use the same account? It would be optimal if I could copy a configuration file so I wouldn't have to apply it one laptop at a time - I could apply it through server administration.

This isn't a typical github setup so don't worry about this being the correct way to set it up.

Comment: Even if you're using one account, consider using separate SSH keys. If one laptop is stolen, you can just revoke its SSH key on Github, without having to put new keys on all the others.

Answer (score 0):

1. Setup the project the way github describes.
2. Create your ssh keys.
3. Tar or Zip everything up.
4. Distribute and Untar/Unzip.
5. Done.

Comment: What do you mean by "everything". Which files?

Comment: the ssh_directory and github project directory. What OS will these be running?

Comment: They will all be on Windows 7 machines

Comment: I also want to be able to put the username and password into the netrc so I can script commands without having to worry about authenticating.

Comment: http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/  Install Git for Windows on all of them. On one of them, make the ssh keys like said. Then just copy over the entire contents of /Users/someuser/.ssh to each machine. If they are different users that's fine, just make sure they all have the .ssh directory and its entire contents. You will also need to copy over the project directory.

Comment: Note, that I don't personally own any windows machines. So I can't verify that the ssh keys are actually at /Users/someuser/.ssh it may be somewhere else. Just find the file *.pub using the search tool. You may make configuring git easier too if you can locate the .gitconfig that Git For Windows uses to set global parameters like name, email, github username, github token, etc...